# How to create CVPixelBuffer attributes dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, cvpixelbuffer, cfdictionary

To create a CVPixelBuffer attributes in **Objective-C** I would do something like so:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
```

And then in the `CVPixelBufferCreate` meathod I would pass `(__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes` as the parameter.

In **Swift** I'm attempting to create my dictionary like this:

```
let attributes:[CFString : NSNumber] = [
        kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey : NSNumber(bool: true),
        kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : NSNumber(bool: true)
    ]
```

but I'm discovering that CFString is not Hashable and well, I have been unable to get this to work.

Can someone provide an example of how this works in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use NSString instead:

```
let attributes:[NSString : NSNumber] = // ... the rest is the same
```

That, after all, is what you were really doing in the Objective-C code; it's just that Objective-C was bridge-casting for you. A CFString cannot be the key in an Objective-C dictionary any more than in a Swift dictionary.

Another (perhaps Swiftier) way is to write this:

```
let attributes : [NSObject:AnyObject] = [
    kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey : true,
    kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : true
]
```

Note that by doing that, we don't have to wrap `true` in an NSNumber either; that will be taken care of for us by Swift's bridging automatically.